# Legoland priority ride?

Tags: san-diego

Should we buy Legoland [Reserve 'N' Ride](https://www.legoland.com/california/tickets-passes/extras-experiences/reserve-n-ride/) tickets?

Context: first time visitors with 4yo, 6yo. They do not like scary / fast rides. will sleep 1 night in the Legoland hotel so would have one afternoon/evening (until 830 pm) and one morning (we can come one hour earlier because of the hotel). Is it worth it to pay extra for the priority ride?

Comment: There are 8 Legolands around the world. I suppose you have to tell us where you are going to get a good answer.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo The question is tagged san-diego, that may be a hint

Comment: I suppose this may depend a lot on the dates involved as this will have an influence on the number of visitors.

Comment: I'll only comment because I have no clue about Legoland etc, but in looking at those tickets I noticed 2 things: 1) The fine print that says "prices starting at $".  When I looked at some dates I saw tickets more expensive than at the starting price. So as per jcaron, dates will matter.  2) It seems you can only buy these tickets for individual days.  So that doubles your ticket cost if you want to have that access on 2 days

Comment: We haven't been to Legoland San Diego since pre covid so been a few years and things may have changed, but IIRC I think only the fast/scary rides had long waits that might benefit from these kinds of passes.  Find out what the rides are that you all really want to do and use the extra hotel-benefit time to do those before the masses arrive.

Comment: I voted to close as opinion-based, as "should we buy?" and "worth it?" queries will not generate declarative answers.